# How to replace &quot; from a string and form valid Json

Tags: json, escaping, double-quotes

I have a json string which has &Quot; inplace of double quotes , and there are quotes inside the json text as well.How do I replace these &Quot; with double quotes only asssociated with key and value and not inside of value , i.e json text .

here is the input :

```
&quot;description&quot;: &quot;First: &quot;Thank you&quot;  always receive a very thorough examination and feel confident with my care&quot;

and OutPut should be :  
"description": "First: &quot;Thank you&quot;  always receive a very thorough examination and feel confident with my care"
```

If replace all the &Quot; it doesn't make a valid json

The quotes i.e &Quot; around Thank you should be retained .

I get this json string from the script tag of a html page , and I am using Java along with  Xpath to fetch content from script tag , and it comes with double quotes encoded as &Quot   .This is how I get the string

```
{&quot;@type&quot;: &quot;Review&quot;,
     &quot;reviewRating&quot;: {
       &quot;@type&quot;: &quot;Rating&quot;,
       &quot;ratingValue&quot;: &quot;5&quot;,
       &quot;bestRating&quot;: &quot;5&quot;,
       &quot;worstRating&quot;: &quot;1&quot;
     },
     &quot;description&quot;: &quot;First: &quot;Thank you&quot;  always receive a very thorough examination and feel confident with my care&quot;,
     &quot;author&quot;: {
       &quot;@type&quot;: &quot;Person&quot;,
       &quot;name&quot;: &quot;Anonymous&quot;
     }
   }

I just want to replace the &Quot value inside the text with any value apart from double quotes ,I don't have control over the source html here
```

Comment: Would tell there is no way in general, but your source is a bit strange or broken, you should start there...

Comment: As you do not tell what platform you are on and which tools you have available, may I suggest Ctrl-H in MS Notepad???

Comment: Please clean up your example; the expected output is kinda strange, as Tom already pointed out. For JSON format see https://www.json.org/ and for validation see https://jsonlint.com/ .

Comment: As has been pointed out, neither the shown input nor the expected output are valid JSON, so your question is to say the least opaque.  Perhaps if you show a larger sample of the input, the real problem you're trying to solve will become  clearer.

Comment: Btw. except missing brackets expected could be valid like this: { "description": "First: &quot;Thank you&quot;  always receive a very thorough examination and feel confident with my care" }